# How to declare an override of a Java method that throws checked exceptions in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to override the following Java method:

```
@Override
public void processMeter(MetricName name, Metered meter, Long epoch)
        throws IOException {
    // implementation
}
```

This Scala declaration does not compile:

```
@throws(classOf[IOException])
override def processMeter(name: MetricName, meter: Metered, epoch: Long) {
    // implementation
}
```

The reported error is:

```
Error:(30, 18) method processMeter overrides nothing
    override def processMeter(name: MetricName, meter: Metered, epoch: Long) {
                 ^
```

I am specifically using Scala 2.9.0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is seeing `scala.Long` instead of `java.lang.Long` so it can't find the method signature to override. Try this:

```
@throws(classOf[IOException])
override def processMeter(name: MetricName, meter: Metered, epoch: java.lang.Long) {
    // implementation
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The difference between `java.lang.Long` and `scala.Long` is confusing at times. I missed this one.